# C++ initialization list

Tags: c++, list, class, initialization

Below is code on initialization lists that I do not entirely understand. In particular it is the very last piece in the page (`red(Bow("red")) and blue(Bow("blue")`).

Bow is another class included in a `.h` file with a constructor of the form `Bow(string aColor)`.

The initialization syntax is

```
ClassName(argumentlist): datamember1(value1), dataMember2(value2){}
```

I do not understand how this initialization works. I understand making an object of class `Bow` in the class `ArcheryCompetition`, it is almost as if the constructor of another class is being called in the initialization list of another constructor. This is all from a beginner book I am reading.

If any more clarification is needed please let me know.

```
class ArcheryCompetition
{
//member variables

private:
    //variables
    int rounds;
    float redScore;
    Bow red;

    float blueScore;
    Bow blue;

public:
    //constructor
    ArcheryCompetition( int lrounds);
    //destructor
    ~ArcheryCompetition();

    //methods
    int compete(void);

};

ArcheryCompetition::ArcheryCompetition(int lrounds):
rounds(lrounds), red(Bow("red")), blue(Bow("blue")), redScore(0), blueScore(0)**
{
}
```

Comment: Which C++ standard are you coding for?

Comment: None yet. Haven't gotten that far. ay tips are welcome.

Comment: It is not *almost as if the constructor of another class is being called*. It is exactly that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since members **red** and **blue** are both instances of class *Bow* it will be sufficient to call ***red("red")*** and ***blue("blue")***. It will call the constructors of class *Bow* with chosen arguments:

```
ArcheryCompetition::ArcheryCompetition(int lrounds):
rounds(lrounds), red("red"), blue("blue"), redScore(0), blueScore(0)
{
}
```

***red(Bow("red"))*** is actually a call to **copy constructor** of class *Bow*.

```
Bow(const Bow& toCopy);
```

It creates temporary instance of *Bow*, calls its constructor with "red" argument and copies this temporary object byte-by-byte to memory reserved for **red** member. I know it can be a little bit confusing and I don't know why such constructions are placed in book without explanation what copy constructor is.

Here you can find some good explanation:
http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/y8hv0pDG/

Comment: Actually, the standard allows the compiler to skip the call to the copy constructor and construct `red` directly. But syntactically you are absolutely right.

Comment: Thank you for your response it is clear and concise. I did not know about copy constructors. Your last paragraph great and is what makes sense to me. Overall this process, the book's method, seems very redundant since the variable is already called Bow in the class declaration. I'll do some research on copy constructors but what data is copied into m_red. What benefit does this have? Does this essentially allow me now to use red.member_function for example without having to directly construct Bow in another manner? Thanks

Comment: @HelloWorld Yes, book's method is redundant, there is no good reason for calling copy constructor in this case. Copy constructors are useful when you already have an instance of, let's say, class Bow and you want to create another instance which will be the copy of previous one.

And again something to read ;) http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/
IMO it's generally a good site about C++ programming and should be added to bookmarks ;)

Comment: Thanks for all the explanations. I think I have enough in the bag to keep be busy for a while. All the fun of learning C++.

Answer (score 1):

For example

```
Bow("red")
```

is calling the `Bow` constructor.

Also you should put the initializers in the same order as the declaration.

Comment: "you should put the initializers in the same order as the declaration" ... because that's the order that the standard mandates that they be initialized, so it's misleading to use a different order. Tell your compiler to warn about them being out of order if it supports that feature.

Answer (score 1):

The initializer

```
red(Bow("red"))
```

calls the `Bow` constructor with argument "red", then initializes `red` with that new (anonymous) `Bow`.

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
 ArcheryCompetition::ArcheryCompetition(int lrounds)
    : rounds(lrounds), red(Bow("red")), blue(Bow("blue")), 
      redScore(0), blueScore(0)
 {
 }
```

is defining a constructor for `ArcheryCompetition` which sets the member variable `rounds` to `lround`, call the `Bow` constructor with `"red"` and sets the `red` member variable (to a copy, so using the copy constructor), etc..

And your terminology is a bit confusing: the C++11 standard gives you [initializer lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Initializer_lists) which are quite different...

Comment: Thank you all for your help. So to further elaborate, Bow being the constructor of another class, what is red actually being populated with? I am having a hard time conceptualizing how this works. It's easy to see how the others are initialized with actual values but initializing a value with the constructor of another class...is this done often? Overall. What is happening when you initialize a variable with the constructor of another class (in general)?

Comment: @Basile, I don't think the confusion is OP's fault. That is really the initialization list and I don't know of any other name for that.

Answer (score 0):

`Bow("red")` will give you a instance of class `Bow`.

`red(Bow("red"))` means initializes date member `red` with `Bow("red")`

Comment: Thank you all for your help. So to further elaborate, Bow being the constructor of another class, what is red actually being populated with? I am having a hard time conceptualizing how this works. It's easy to see how the others are initialized with actual values but initializing a value with the constructor of another class...is this done often? Overall. What is happening when you initialize a variable with the constructor of another class (in general)?

Comment: @HelloWorld "the constructor of another class" -- what other class? `red` is a `Bow`, and thus is initialized to a `Bow` ... the one constructed by `Bow("red")`.

Answer (score 0):

Walk thru what the following do.

```
Bow("red");

Bow red("red");

Bow red = Bow("red");

Bow redbow("red"); Bow red(redbow);
```

If you get these but are still struggling with

```
red(Bow("red"))
```

then this would be a good time to learn not to give member variables ambiguous names that don't distinguish them from local variables, e.g.

```
class ArcheryCompetition
{
...
    int m_rounds;
    Bow m_red;
    Bow m_blue;
...

    ArcheryCompetition(int rounds_) // distinguish parameters from local variables too
        : m_rounds(rounds_)
        , m_red(Bow("red"))
        , m_blue(Bow("blue"))
        ...
    {}
...
};
```

After a Constructor declaration, the ":" syntax denotes an "initializer list" where you initialize the members of the class - where initialization means construction. It is basically a way to say "When I am being constructed, this is how my members should be constructed" - so you are exactly right that the constructors of the other classes are being called; they are being called, in-place, on your classes members, to your specification. Thus "m_blue(Bow("Blue"))" tells the compiler to call the Bow constructor with the argument "blue" to initialize the m_blue member during invocations of this constructor.

Except in this case, by adding the class name, what you are actually doing is

```
Bow redbow("red");
m_red(redbow);
```

Which creates a temporary Bow objected initialized with the value "red" and then uses Bow's copy constructor to copy the data into m_red.

you could actually simplify (improve) the constructor down to

```
    ArcheryCompetition(int rounds_) // distinguish parameters from local variables too
        : m_rounds(rounds_)
        , m_red("red")
        , m_blue("blue")
        ...
    {}
```

EDIT:

When you see

```
class MyClass {
    int i;
     YourClass m_yourClass1, m_yourClass2;

public:
    MyClass()
      : m_i(10)
      , m_yourClass1( YourClass(1) )
      , m_yourClass2( 2 )
    {}
};

void foo() {
     MyClass myClass;
     ...
}
```

Then, roughly, that first line of "foo" causes something like this to happen:

```
MyClass* myClassPtr = make_room_on_stack_for(sizeof(MyClass));

// : m_i(10)
myClassPtr->m_i = 10;

// , m_yourClass1( YourClass(1) )
YourClass* temporary = make_room_on_stack_for(sizeof(YourClass));
temporary->YourClass(1);
if(YourClass has a copy constructor (YourClass::YourClass(const YourClass&))
    myClassPtr->m_yourClass1->YourClass(temporary); // copy constructor
else
    myClassPtr->m_yourClass1->operator=(temporary); // assignment operator
delete temporary;

// , m_yourClass2( 2 )
myClassPtr->m_yourClass2->YourClass(2);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response it is clear and concise. I did not know about copy constructors. Your last paragraph great and is what makes sense to me. Overall this process, the book's method, seems very redundant since the variable is already called Bow in the class declaration. I'll do some research on copy constructors but what data is copied into m_red. What benefit does this have? Thanks

Comment: It doesn't have any benefit, I think they thought it would be more readable or perhaps it leads to them explaining copy constructors. The variable isn't *called* Bow, that syntax denotes calling the constructor for Bow and creating a temporary Bow object.

Comment: I added an extended explanation to my answer.